# What are the risks in moving from GDR to CU servicing option?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have SQL server 2019 with RTM baseline and GDR patches are applied.

I am reading that GDR only contains security fixes and CU contains security + functional fixes. I also know that you are allowed to make a change from GDR updates to CU updates ONE TIME. Once a SQL Server CU update is applied to a SQL Server installation, there is NO way to go back to the GDR update path.

In planning to move from GDR to CU update, what are the risks involved?

Comment: Any future GDR patches will be fixed in the CU train as well, although you may have to update to the _latest_ CU to get the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The risk is that CUs change how SQL Server functions. Let's see some examples.

KB4040533 fixes incorrect results on a calculated column when a trace flag is enabled. After the CU is installed, the calculated column content is going to be different what developers used to think. What if they, for whatever the reason, use the value anyway? After CU installation, the results are not the same. At least some CI test is going to break. Or if you patch one test instance but not another, those two are going to have different results.

Another one is KB4039284. There's a new keyword for statistics. If developers use it, the script is no longer backwards compatible, even if the SQL Server major version is the same.

Then there is KB4046914, which adds a CXPACKET wait type to execution plans. Oops, now your home-made plan analyser won't work anymore, as it doesn't know about the wait in plan XML.